# QBFC12 Installer doesn't seem to be working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, qbfc

I am getting the error message that QBFC12 is not registered. "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C693D8F1-180B-4F82-B735-8F511B566718} failed due to the following error: 80040154."  I run the QBFC12_0 installer (several times), but I still get this message.  I developed this on VS2012, using VB.NET, and I used the InstallShield installer that comes with VS2012 to install the program.  what else do I need to do?

Comment: When you created your installer, did you make sure to include the Merge Modules for QBFC12 as well as the Xerces2.5.0 module? If you don't include these then you will need to manually install QBFC12 on any computer that you install your software on.

Answer (score 0):

you try to run the QBFC12 installer again? perhaps its not properly registered on your machine.